# Read text from image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am planning to make an app using phonegap. This app will read text from image. So my question is that can we read text from images using javascript? I know we can do this using java but I need to do this using javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why fo you need it to be javascript based? Hav you been thinking about using 3rd party service such as http://ocrsdk.com/

Comment: Since I am using phonegap. So for this i will make it using JavaScript. Is there any other open source JavaScript libraries? I searched but could not find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OCRs in Javascript are not very powerfull.
I found a libraries who uses simple Euclidean Distance comparisons. The accuracy is not perfect, but it does do a reasonably good job.
[Link](http://www.heatonresearch.com/fun/ocr)